# Is there any cloud vm that can be in suspended state

Tags: virtual-machine, amazon-web-services, cloud

I have checked AWS & GCE &DO and a few others - none of them support leaving a VM in a suspended state while we can do so with VMWare on our local. 
Any reason for this feature not being available ?

Comment: What is your motivation?  Cost?  Hot migrations?  Is there a legitimate need for this, when instances can be stopped and started, including for capacity changes?  Stopped instances benefit you ($) and the provider, because they deallocate the compute capacity so that it can be sold to someone else.  When you start back up, hardware is again allocated.  Would the same be possible with suspend?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can suspend a VM. For example, this would work on EC2 instance running Ubuntu 16.04:

`sudo systemctl suspend`

You won't be able to wake the instance up though.

Suspending is a native feature of KVM, so cloud providers could implement such a feature relatively easy. Why didn't they? I guess no one really needs it. If you still want to "freeze" execution of some environment, just use Docker and then `docker pause`.

Comment: So if I suspend the EC2 instance it would go into a coma ? No use then. 

One reason could be to have running instances (more$), as suspend would make it very easy to fire up an instance on demand and not have  to go through starting servers etc. Yeah, in production no one really trusts suspended state (we use it all the time in dev otherwise a lot of time is wasted) 

I did try out Docker but was put off when many said the FS in docker would not support incremental state and suspends or something to that effect, but I now see that it is far more advanced..thanks for the heads up